# PostgreSQL: Flip Rows and Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a PosgreSQL table called `store_properties`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM store_properties
```

provides this data, which has hundreds of rows returned:

| name | value | last_modified_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| address | 123 Main St | 2022-03-23 16:05:04 |
| city | Cityville | 2022-03-23 16:05:04 |
| state | AL | 2022-03-23 16:05:04 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I need to write a query that returns the `name` field as the column aliases and `value` as the fields with just 1 row. Example:

| address | city | state | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 Main St | Cityville | AL | ... |

How can this be done? I do not have access to create functions or add plugins.

Comment: How do you know which rows belong together (to make up the columns)?

Comment: For each row in `store_properties`, the `name` would become an alias and the `value` would be the value of said alias.

Comment: What do you do to distinguish `address` for a store in `city` 'Cityville' from `address` for a store in `city` 'Gotham' ?

Comment: Whoever created this table used the `name` field as a strange psudo-unique key. There will never be a duplicate for any of the values. The information in this table is unique for one store.